# Where does Ubuntu Touch store "usermetrics"

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Meizu phone and installed an app called Blabble. After deinstalling it still displays information on the Welcome screen "flower". I would like to get rid of this. I found that there is a folder somewhere called usermetrics, which is the source for the info in the "flower". However, it is not in the location given here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/cplusplus/usermetrics/index.html Can someone help me? There is already a bug report for this on the Blabble site on launchpad, but the developer doesn't seem to work on it anymore.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Thomas